# swipe to dismiss undo like gmail

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe-gesture

i want to add swiping like [this](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo), actually this library is of Android. i want in swift.

i have used by default method of tableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

But the problem is it provide only one way of Swipe not both left and right.

and also in **GMAIL**  app there is both end swiping and even we we swipe two time to that row it will be deleted automatically.

please guide me how to do that. i am not able to find any third party.

one thing that i have created to add both side gesture left and right and then add Button in their method but nothing happen.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {



        let moreRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "More", handler:{
            action, indexpath in

            print("MORE ACTION");

            self.Selected = "YES"

           self.selectedValue = indexpath.row

            self.tableView.rowHeight = 50

            self.tableView.beginUpdates()

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 0)

            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        });

        moreRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0);

        let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in
            print("DELETE ACTION");

            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        });


    let Action = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "", handler:{action, indexpath in
        print("ACTION");
    });

    if self.Selected == "YES" {

        if self.selectedValue == indexPath.row {

            return [Action];
        }
        //return [Action];
        return [deleteRowAction, moreRowAction];
    }else{
    return [deleteRowAction, moreRowAction];
    }
}
```

and the method that allow editing

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

           return false
    }
```

**for gesture**

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(ViewController.left(_:)))


    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeleft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self,  action: #selector(ViewController.right(_:)))

    swipeleft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeleft)



 func left(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
            print("left");
//what to write inside to make custom button here
        }
        func right(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
            print("right");
        }
```

Comment: why don't you add a custom cell with both views inside (contents, actions) on swipe you switch between them

Comment: @Mad Burea have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy approach to Achieve this solution with UISwipeGesture and UITableviewCell

import UIKit

```
class TableViewCustomCell:UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    let leftSwipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipe(_:)))
    leftSwipe.direction = .Left;
    self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

}

func swipe(touch: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    let swipeGesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = sender as! UISwipeGestureRecognizer
    //Write your code to Unread or 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be creating a gesture recognizer that triggers a certain function in which you can deploy your own code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {        
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.leftSwiped))
    swipeLeft.delegate = self
    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    self.tableView!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
 }

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func leftSwiped() {

}
```